# MVVM: When DataContext is not null by using DataTemplate to bind viewmodel(DataContext) to the view

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

In the main XAML:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:GraphicEditorPropertyViewModel}">
    <views:GraphicEditorPropertyView/>
</DataTemplate>
```

In Class GraphicEditorPropertyView.xaml.cs

```
public partial class GraphicEditorPropertyView : UserControl
{
    private bool SecurityLevelBar_MouseCaptured = false;

    public GraphicEditorPropertyView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Int32 pattern = ((GraphicEditorPropertyViewModel)(this.DataContext)).CurrentGraphicEditorVgProperty.Pattern;
        UInt32 frontColor = ((GraphicEditorPropertyViewModel)(this.DataContext)).CurrentGraphicEditorVgProperty.FrontColor;
        UInt32 backColor = ((GraphicEditorPropertyViewModel)(this.DataContext)).CurrentGraphicEditorVgProperty.BackColor;
        ConvertPattern2BrushCanvas convertPattern2BrushCanvas = new ConvertPattern2BrushCanvas(((GraphicEditorPropertyViewModel)(this.DataContext)).Parent.CurrentLibDiagramDesigner);
        Brush brush = convertPattern2BrushCanvas.Convert(new object[] { frontColor, backColor, pattern }, null, null, null) as Brush;

        Selected_Pattern.Fill = brush;
    }

    private void WindowPattern_MouseClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Button button = sender as Button;
        Brush buttonBrush = button.Background;
        Selected_Pattern.Fill = buttonBrush;

        ((GraphicEditorPropertyViewModel)(this.DataContext)).CurrentGraphicEditorVgProperty.Pattern = System.Convert.ToInt32(button.ToolTip.ToString());
    }
}
```

}

**DataContext** in the **constructor** is **null**;

**DataContext** in the function **WindowPattern_MouseClick** is **NOT** null;

Why?

Comment: You should be using a converter to do this, not codebehind.  If, for no other reason, you wouldn't have to worry about the fact that the DataContext hasn't been set prior to the construction of the view, which it hasn't.  To do what you want you either need to override the metadata of the DataContextProperty in order to add a property changed watcher, or you need to offload this DataContext fiddling until after the application has loaded via Dispatcher.BeginInvoke.  But an IValueConverter would be the simplest to do.

Answer (score 0):

Because the `DataContext` has to be set. It's just a normal property.

Think about how **you** would set the `DataContext` on an object. You'd create the object first (thus running the entire constructor) then you'd set the `DataContext` property.

That's what the system is doing under the hood.

Comment: DataTemplate set the DataContext for me. Whenever I attached a view model like 
        <metro:MetroContentControl x:Name="GraphicEditorWindowContent" Content="{Binding GraphicEditorWindowContent}"/>. The view will create automatically. DataContext will get set to the view model.

Comment: The thing is the datacontext in function WindowPattern_MouseClick is usable.